# Groovy: how to get properties declared in base class

Tags: reflection, properties, groovy

In the following code, I need all the properties available in `Child` class (i.e. `foo, bar`). I am not interested in all other properties added by groovy.

```
class Parent {def foo}
class Child extends Parent {def bar}
```

So far none of these gets the result:

```
println Child.fields
println Child.properties.each{k,v->println "$k -> $v"}
println Child.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.collect {it.name}
println Child.methods.findAll {it.name.startsWith("get")}.collect {it.name}
```

I am trying to find out some direct method which would give me this.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you what you need:

```
assert ['foo', 'class', 'bar'] == B.metaClass.properties*.name
```

Comment: it returns `'class'` as well, I need something like what `declaredFields` does

Comment: Then just add a `findAll`: `B.metaClass.properties*.name.findAll{ it != 'class'}`

Answer (score 0):

What about checking an instance? Also, i missed the `extends` in `Child`

```
class A { def foo }
class B extends A { def bar }

b = new B(foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar')

assert b.properties == [foo: 'foo', class: B, bar: 'bar']
```

Comment: Thanks for `extends` part, I have updated the code in question. Actually here I won't have instance of classes. I have to get all properties declared in the class and then add some methods to class based on those properties.